# iframe and text positioning

Tags: html, iframe, css

I have created a small menu of new items and would like to have the "facebook like" iframe position in front of them. but when i drop the html code it appears floating above the text/link. i have uploaded a screen shot

http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/9343/likeoverflow.jpg

you can see the text appearing underneath.

What css am i missing?

Comment: Can you provide some code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're missing a background colour on the overlay:

```
.facebook-like-overlay {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* other css declarations */
}
```

That will stop the text below from showing through.